# InDesign: hiding center line between two facing pages

Tags: adobe-indesign, tools

I'm wondering how I can make the center line between two pages disappear, for example:

[image]

Comment: Are you asking to do this just for aesthetic reasons when designing?

Comment: doing a magazine for school and needs to look professional

Comment: so would help getting the line out of the way

Comment: Typically the line between pages is only visible to *you* while working in inDesign and is nothing to be concerned about. You could set up pages in spreads if you *really* don't want to see the individual page divisions. That can, and usually will, cause pagination issues later for larger documents.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot turn off the black line as that indicates the edge of the page for facing pages.

But you can turn off Overprint Preview by making sure it is unchecked under View -> Overprint Preview. Objects that are over the 2 facing pages will not show the black line.

[image: Overprint preview]

Comment: It was already unchecked, so that can't be it...

Comment: @stormw I am not sure then if you have Overprint already unchecked. The black line indicates the edge of the page because you have facing pages and is not something you can turn off. If you're worried about it looking unprofessional, the black line will not be exported with your design.

Comment: so strange i can't get it to work. It's already unchecked as I said... Yeah hopefully it'll go away when I export it:) thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Choose Edit > Preferences > Guides & Pasteboard (Windows) or
   InDesign > Preferences > Guides & Pasteboard (Mac OS).
2. Select **Guides in Back**, and click OK.
3. Make sure View > Overprint preview is **OFF**

Obviously, this black guide will still show up where no block is overlapping.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that you need to make sure you need to export as 'Spreads' not 'Pages'. See image below for how to adjust the export settings.

[image: Export settings]

Comment: If this is for a school magazine that should be printed, you absolutely **do not** want to export spreads. In fact, you rarely want to export spreads in general, except when showing prepress proofs to clients or when printing book covers.